# Boost asio undefined reference TLS_method, TLS_client_method etc

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ssl, boost, tls1.2

Good day ! I'm currently developing a large p2p communication service and I'm using mongoose web server, I've started using SSL and in order to send data I figured I can use asio from Boost. Thing is I get an error at compile time, multiple errors actually.

```
In function `boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:97: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:105: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:113: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:142: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:150: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:158: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:180: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:188: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:196: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:225: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:233: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:241: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:269: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:272: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:275: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:281: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:286: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:291: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
../Anonymous/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/libanonymous.a(http_operations.o): In function `boost::asio::ssl::context::~context()':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:358: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_default_passwd_cb_userdata'
../Anonymousy/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/libanonymous.a(http_operations.o): In function `boost::asio::ssl::context::set_options(long, boost::system::error_code&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:453: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
```

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

char* process_http(int sockfd, char *host, char *page, char *poststr) {
    //This is to avoid application crash when we perform write() or read.
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    ssize_t n;
    int sendlineSize = strlen(page) + MAXLINE + 1;
    char sendline[sendlineSize];
    char *recvline = (char *) malloc(sizeof (char) * (sendlineSize));

    sprintf(sendline, "POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n"
            "Host: %s\r\n"
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
            "%s", page, host, (int) strlen(poststr), poststr);

    if (write(sockfd, sendline, sizeof (sendline)) == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((n = read(sockfd, recvline, sendlineSize)) != 0) {
        recvline[n] = '\0';
    }

    return recvline; //this must be freed by the receiver!! ( allocated here! )
}
```

I doubt that the code is the problem, I've tried changing the flags, which are:

```
-lpthread -lrt -ldl -lboost_serialization -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -ltomcrypt -DLTM_DESC -lcrypto -lcrypt -fno-rtti -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread -lssl -lcrypto -lboost_system
```

I'm using Boost for serialization and some file parsing so I doubt that the boost library has an issue, the boost library version is 1.64 and the OpenSSL version is OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017. 
I've verified all the libraries and they seem fine but I can't seem to find a cause. I'm also using Netbeans, I'm not compiling it using command line. The project is rather big so I'm thinking the linker has a problem detecting the methods in question.

Comment: Try changing the link order (at the end) to: `-lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto`. If that alone doesn't work, try adding `-ldl -lz` at the very end

Comment: Sorry, it did't work, tried them both and nothing but thank you for the advice !

Comment: @aptamil Yes it works, add them at the end, not before the .cpp